# Stamp out and transfer values from one overlayed vector layer to another

Tags: vector, overlay

I have a vector layer with administrative boundaries and another vector layer with postal code boundaries, which are more precise/smaller entities/objects.  I now want to transmit the values of one column/attribute of the first layer to the second.

Is it possible to overlay them and kind of stamp out this attribute and thus transfer it to the postal code layer?

Comment: Are you trying to add the name of the administrative boundary to the postal code layer? If so have you tried a spatial join?

Comment: we would need to know what software you are interested in using to help further.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't mentioned what software you are using, I will assume you are using ArcGIS.  What you want to do is perform a spatial join and then update a field using the calculate field tool.

You can find information about a Spatial Join [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000).

And here is information about the [Calculate Field tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_the_Calculate_Field_tool/005s00000029000000/).

You might want to be aware of cases where the postal code boundaries cross multiple administrative  boundaries, if that happens at all.  How will you account for those cases?  In those instances, you might want to include all administrative boundaries in the field and separate them with a comma.